# Financial types in contribution is always default and not taken from contribution page

Tags: contributions, financial-types

I have contribution pages for different membership classes. Each page has a different Financial Type so that the transactions can be exported and the accounts differ for each membership type. However no matter what Financial Type is set in the contribution page it seems that 'a default' gets associated with the contribution. This does not happen for Events where the Financial Type is correctly picked up from the Event.

Maybe I have something set up incorrectly but it looks like a bug to me.

Cheers
Martin Fuggle

Comment: When you ask a question you need to very careful to use the terms used in CiviCRM.   CiviCRM does not have "membership classes", do you mean "membership types"?  Also you need to be as specific as you can be in your question. What do you mean by "a default"?  Do you mean the financial type you specifed when you defined the membership type or do you mean something else?   My answer at http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9744/why-is-a-contribution-given-a-financial-type-different-from-that-allocated-to-th/12450#12450 may help you understand what should happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Price Sets on the contribution pages - i.e. you selected *Click here if you want to configure the Regular Fees below as part of a Price Set, with the added flexibility and complexity that entails* - then it may be that the financial type is being taken from the price set rather than from the contribution page settings.

Also note the distinction between the financial type of the contribution and the financial type of line items - see discussion at [Contribution Page Price Sets Not Recording Different Financial Types](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-13683).

However in the similar question [Why is a contribution given a financial type different from that allocated to the contribution page used?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9744/why-is-a-contribution-given-a-financial-type-different-from-that-allocated-to-th), price sets were not the issue and a solution was not recorded.

Comment: This is not the issue. I have a Contribution Page which is used for online membership contributions. The Financial Type that is associated with the page is not carried through to the Accounting Records as stated in the pop help documentation. No matter what Financial Type is associated with the Contribution Page for Memberships the Financial Type that is associated with the accounting records is the default Financial Type. As far as I can tell this is an error. However I may have something configured incorrectly but I am not able to see what it might be.

Comment: A Contribution Page may be used for online membership contributions with or without configuring a Price Set. If you confirm whether or not you have configured a Price Set for yours, this will help pin down the issue.